# How to generate .pdb file in Visual Studio 2019 for C++ from command line

Tags: c++, command, line

I am using `cl.exe` **C++ compiler** in `Visual Studio 2019` from the command line. But, I am unable to set the required flag to produce a .pdb file to debug in a separate debugger. I tried `/DEBUG:FULL /FI /Fd`, etc., as read in several posts, but no .pdb file is generated.

I also tried to configure the IDE as per different instructions, but still, no .pdb file is created.

What is the command-line flag to be used to produce a `.pdb` file?

`cl.exe myprogram.cpp /DEBUG:FULL /Fdmyprogram.pdb /Famyprogram.asm /Femyprogram.exe`

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdb-use-program-database?view=msvc-160  Note this is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=msvc-160) not a [cl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=msvc-160) option,  Question why use `cl` from the command line? Why not the IDE or if you need to use the command line then MSBuild or CMake ?

Answer (score 3):

The `PDB` file is generated by *linker*, not *compiler* directly.

Basically, just generate an executable or dll file, by `link`ing the `*.obj` files.

While `GCC` can directly link, the MSVC has a completely different *.exe file for that purpose.

> See the docs for linker (`link.exe`):
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linking?view=msvc-160
>
> Or compiler (`cl.exe`):
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-command-line-syntax?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 2):

You can add linker options after `/link` command. Try

```
cl.exe myprogram.cpp /Z7
```